# make android splash screen animation with xml

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen

I want to make an animated splash screen in android related to quiz. Can anyone help me for making the splash screen which gives good start to my application of quiz?

Comment: splash screen keeps user waiting getting to the main screen of the app. If your doing lot of work like getting data for network or loading game resources at the start then show splash screen. Read http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are not specific about the type of animation you want, i will just limit this answer to options from Android Animation class.

The Animation(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) class in android is basically divided into four types AlphaAnimation, RotateAnimation, ScaleAnimation, TranslateAnimation. Each one manipulate a particular type of object property.

AplahAmianation: An animation that controls the alpha level of an object. Useful for fading things in and out.

RotateAnimation: An animation that controls the rotation of an object

ScaleAnimation: An animation that controls the scale of an object. You can specify the point to use for the center of scaling.

TranslateAnimation: An animation that controls the position of an object

you can also use AnimationsSet to Represents a group of Animations that should be played together.

I will use one of the properties as an example then you can pick it up from there.

```
AlphaAnimation alpha;
TextView splashText, splashText2;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        splashText2.setVisibility(1);
        splashText2.setText(splashText2.getText().toString() + ".");

    }
};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    alpha= new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    alpha.setDuration(1000);
    handler = new Handler();


    splashText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slash_test);

Thread myTread = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(1500);
            handler.post(runnable);
            sleep(500);
            handler.post(runnable);
            sleep(500); 
            handler.post(runnable);
            sleep(500); 
            handler.post(runnable);

            Intent changeActivity = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, WelcomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(changeActivity);


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
              finish();
        }


        };
            };
       myTread.start();
       splashText.setAnimation(alpha);

    }
```

this will create a splascreen that will make a text fade-in and continuously animate loading...
the line

```
splashText2.setVisibility(1);
```

will change the degree of visibility from 0 to 1

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I need an animated screen with xml in android 
and I want an example of splash screen related to quiz or idea for making animated screen for quiz game
I need an idea that what I can do for splash screen of quiz game means what I can include so that it looks attractive
and thank you for your reply